# Fail with error 'Incorrect Ether amount'

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, presale

I am trying to set up a very basic presale using Remix IDE.

[image: I have set up the "Price" and token address as follows]

0x96AAC35C248C48418eF9A939e3eB8b9a64207532 --> Presale Contract
0xF60EeA9ab4B520846CA01D368A08cD4b71B619f8 --> Token itself

This is only a test for me, but im getting stuck at the point of actually trying to purchase the tokens.

Token.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("WittyWhaleWallet", "WWW") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000000000000000); // Mint 1,000,000 tokens
    }
}
```

Presale.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Presale is Ownable {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    IERC20 public token;
    uint256 public tokenPrice; // Token price in wei
    uint256 public tokensSold;
    bool public isPresaleActive;

    event TokensPurchased(address indexed buyer, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _tokenAddress, uint256 _tokenPrice, address _owner) Ownable(_owner) {
        token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
        isPresaleActive = true;
    }

    modifier onlyWhilePresaleActive() {
        require(isPresaleActive, "Presale is not active");
        require(msg.value == 0, "Ether not accepted during presale");
        _;
    }

    function purchaseTokens(uint256 _amount) external payable onlyWhilePresaleActive {
        uint256 requiredEther = _amount * tokenPrice;
        require(msg.value == requiredEther, "Incorrect Ether amount");

        // Log balances and allowances for debugging
        console.log('Token balance before purchase:', token.balanceOf(address(this)));
        console.log('Buyer token allowance:', token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)));

        require(token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _amount, "Purchase failed: Insufficient allowance");
        require(token.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Purchase failed: Insufficient tokens");

        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        tokensSold += _amount;

        // Log updated balances and allowances for debugging
        console.log('Token balance after purchase:', token.balanceOf(address(this)));
        console.log('Buyer token allowance after purchase:', token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)));

        emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function endPresale() external onlyOwner {
        isPresaleActive = false;
    }

    function withdrawFunds() external onlyOwner {
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

HTML Code for dapp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Token Purchase dApp</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.3.6/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Token Purchase dApp</h1>

<div>
  <button onclick="connectWallet()">Connect Wallet</button>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="tokenAmount">Token Amount:</label>
  <input type="number" id="tokenAmount" min="1" placeholder="Enter amount">
  <button onclick="purchaseTokens()">Purchase Tokens</button>
</div>

<script>
  let web3;
  let contractAddress = '0x96AAC35C248C48418eF9A939e3eB8b9a64207532'; // Replace with your presale contract address
  let contractABI = [
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_tokenAddress",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_tokenPrice",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "target",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "AddressEmptyCode",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "account",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "AddressInsufficientBalance",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "endPresale",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "FailedInnerCall",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnableInvalidOwner",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "account",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnableUnauthorizedAccount",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "token",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "SafeERC20FailedOperation",
        "type": "error"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "previousOwner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "purchaseTokens",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "payable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "renounceOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "buyer",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "TokensPurchased",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "newOwner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferOwnership",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "withdrawFunds",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "isPresaleActive",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "owner",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "token",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "contract IERC20",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "tokenPrice",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "tokensSold",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];

async function connectWallet() {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    try {
      await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

      // Check if MetaMask supports the 'disconnect' event
      if (window.ethereum.on) {
        window.ethereum.on('close', handleDisconnect);
        window.ethereum.on('disconnect', handleDisconnect);
      } else {
        console.warn('MetaMask does not support the new disconnect event.');
      }

      web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      console.log('Connected to MetaMask');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting to MetaMask:', error.message);
    }
  } else {
    console.error('MetaMask not detected!');
  }
}

function handleDisconnect() {
  console.log('Disconnected from MetaMask');
  // Handle any necessary cleanup or UI changes on disconnect
}

async function purchaseTokens() {
  try {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      // Request user accounts
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

      // Your existing code for token purchase
      let tokenAmount = document.getElementById('tokenAmount').value;
      if (!tokenAmount || isNaN(tokenAmount) || tokenAmount <= 0) {
        alert('Please enter a valid token amount');
        return;
      }

      let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
      let tokenAmountNumeric = parseFloat(tokenAmount);
      let tokenAmountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(tokenAmountNumeric.toString(), 'ether');

      // Removed gas estimation temporarily
      // let gas = await contract.methods.purchaseTokens(tokenAmountInWei).estimateGas();
      // console.log('Gas estimate:', gas);

      let transaction = await contract.methods.purchaseTokens(tokenAmountInWei)
        .send({
          from: accounts[0],
          gas: 200000,  // Use a fixed gas value for testing, you can adjust it later
        });

      console.log('Transaction hash:', transaction.transactionHash);
      alert('Tokens purchased successfully!');
    } else {
      console.error('Web3 object not initialized. Make sure to connect your wallet first.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error purchasing tokens:', error.message);
    alert('Error purchasing tokens. Please check the console for details.');
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```